# Multiple users updating data to firebase at a time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have build an anroid app which uses firebase where in i send my data. I have a form in my app. the data from the form is sent to firebase. If two users are entering the data simultanously, and one of the users update the data first, the filled data in the other user's form is cleared. I need a solution to this issue. How can i avoid data being cleared from other users forms?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement transaction operations. [Linked documentation here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

Answer (score 0):

If you need per-user storage in the database, it doesn't make sense to store everyone's data in the same location in the database.  Instead, use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) to get your users logged in with a unique user id, and use that user id to [store user data in a dedicated location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security) in the database.